# Locate email address within Case.Description using regex

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, email2case, pattern

My apex proficiency is pretty low so I may be on the wrong track on this. But I'm attempting to take an email address from a set Email to Case email we get and apply it to a field (I'll be doing additional automation in flow if its set) by taking it from the completed case description (It makes up a small specific volume of our email queue, so case trigger seems ideal)

But these emails follow a fairly set format which includes the lines:
The user's email address is: XXXX@XXXXX.com
The user's phone number is: 5555555555

I just want an apex trigger that grabs the email address and applies it to a field.

I had attempted the following based on some other public resources, it will compile but It's not working.

> ```
> trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert) {
>
> for (Case c: Trigger.new) {
>     if (c.Origin == 'E2C: Specificvalue'){
>
>  Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile('(?i).*\\s([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4})\\s?');
>         Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(c.Description);
>         
>         if (emailMatcher.matches()) {
>             c.Description_Email__c = emailMatcher.group(1);
>         } else {
>         }
>     }
> }
> }
> ```

Comment: How do you know if the description is written well formatted. For email like `abc@email.com`, description could be : asjfdhf..sdfs.asdasdabc@email.com

Comment: It's an automated email from a vendor, so it is reliable for this specific case type which is associated with it's own email to case address

Comment: Can you try with this pattern : `Pattern.compile('^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$');` also if it doesn't work, share an example description.

Comment: I'm not able to provide too many specifics, but the portion of the email that begins with The user's email address is: is around 400 characters into the email